# Hover Action over own Annotation in Eclipse (Plugin)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, annotations, hover, mouseover

I have created a Plugin that uses an own Annotation Marker. Now I want to add a special Hover Action, when I mouseover this special Marker. I don't really know where to add this action. I allready read about the IAnnotationHover Interface, but how do I access the vertical ruler of the ordinary workbench text editor to add/change the AnnotationHover?

p.s.: just to be more precise, I use the common editor of Eclipse, not an own editor... so I think I should not override SourceViewerConfiguration or the IAnnotationHover
any idea so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956666/creating-a-eclipse-plugin-with-text-hover) to create a custom Hover on the Default Java Editor.

Here's a custom implementation of @PKeidel's LangHover class from that question for your specific use case, combined with a [custom script to detect java elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813812/how-to-find-the-type-of-a-selected-member-in-eclipse). Note that you should change `ANNOTATION_NAME`'s value to the value of your custom Annotation, and the return value of `getHoverInfo` to whatever you want the custom hover to contain.

```java
public class LangHover implements IJavaEditorTextHover
{
    public static final String ANNOTATION_NAME = "YourCustomAnnotation";

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public static ICodeAssist getCodeAssist(IEditorPart fEditor)
    {
        if (fEditor != null) {
            IEditorInput input= fEditor.getEditorInput();
            if (input instanceof IClassFileEditorInput) {
                IClassFileEditorInput cfeInput= (IClassFileEditorInput) input;
                return cfeInput.getClassFile();
            }

            WorkingCopyManager manager= JavaPlugin.getDefault().getWorkingCopyManager();
            return manager.getWorkingCopy(input, false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static IEditorPart getActiveEditor()
    {
        IWorkbenchWindow window= PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            IWorkbenchPage page= window.getActivePage();
            if (page != null) {
                return page.getActiveEditor();
            }
        }
        return null;
    } 

    // When this returns true, the custom hover should be shown.
    public static boolean elementIsCustomAnnotation(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion)
    {
        IEditorPart activeEditor = getActiveEditor();
        ICodeAssist resolve = getCodeAssist(activeEditor);
        IJavaElement[] detectedJavaElements = null;

        if (resolve != null)
        {
            try
            {
                detectedJavaElements = resolve.codeSelect(hoverRegion.getOffset(), hoverRegion.getLength());
            }
            catch (JavaModelException x)
            {
                System.out.println("JavaModelException occured");
            }
        }

        for (IJavaElement javaElement : detectedJavaElements)
        {
            // If I found an element of type IJavaElement.ANNOTATION
            // and its name equals ANNOTATION_NAME, return true
            if (javaElement.getElementType() == IJavaElement.ANNOTATION && javaElement.getElementName().equals(ANNOTATION_NAME))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;           
    }

    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textviewer, IRegion region)
    {
        if(elementIsCustomAnnotation(textviewer, region))
        {
            return "Your own hover text goes here"";
        }
        return null; // Shows the default Hover (Java Docs)
    }
}
```

Basically, what is happening here is that `elementIsCustomAnnotation` is checking the java element(s) the user is hovering over, puts them in the `detectedJavaElements` array, and then checks that array to find an Annotation with name equal to `ANNOTATION_NAME`.