# Creating a eclipse plugin with text hover

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I would like to make a `Eclipse plugin` (text editor). I would "read" the text under the cursor and show a dynamical generated hover that depends on the text. Now I have the problem that I don't know how I can read the text and "add" the hover.

It's my first `Eclipse Plugin` so I am happy for each tip I can get.

Edit:

I'd like to integrate it into the default `Eclipse` `Java` editor. I have tried to create a new `plugin` with a editor template but I think it is the wrong way.

Last Edit:

The answer from PKeidel is exactly what I'm looking for :)

Thanks PKeidel

Comment: please explain what youv got right now, an editor-view? an plugin-skeleton?

Comment: What a java-element do you need to mark?http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/util/package-summary.html

Comment: I would mark a String parameter for a method. Now I have a new Editor with a working Hover. But I would integrate the Hover into the Default Java Editor. I make it with an own SourceViewerConfiguration. How can I add the Hover Configuration to the Default Editor but nothing else? (Synthax Highlighting, CodeScanner, ...)

Comment: @phoenix have you managed to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fault is that you created a completly new Editor instead of a plugin for the existing Java Editor. Plugins will be activated via `extension points`. In your case you have to use `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers` [more...](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaEditorTextHovers.html).

```
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers">
      <hover
            activate="true"
            class="path.to_your.hoverclass"
            id="id.path.to_your.hoverclass">
      </hover>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

The class argument holds the path to your Class that `implements IJavaEditorTextHover`.

```
public class LangHover implements IJavaEditorTextHover
{
    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textviewer, IRegion region)
    {
         if(youWantToShowAOwnHover)
           return "Your own hover Text goes here"";
         return null; // Shows the default Hover (Java Docs)
    }
}
```

That should do it ;-)