# How to find the type of a selected member in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I am co-developing an Eclipse plugin where Users can select Classes and Methods from their code and attach them to notes that are saved in a different file.

I want to find a way to determine what type of member was selected by the user when they choose to create an attachment.

For example:

I want to attach a class named "HelloClass" to a note called "HelloNote". I select the "HelloClass" member name in the editor, right-click and select my "Create Attachment" action. This action calls the "createAttachment" method, which already contains all the functionality for creating this attachment between the Class and the Note. However, I need to know whether the attached member is a Class or a Method. This information is neccessary, because if a Method is attached, I want to show the class it belongs to on the Note Attachment TreeView that my plugin offers.

My first instinct was using the [Java Parser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) library to parse the entire file and look for the matching member name, but this can result in other problems (for example, two classes in the same file that share a method name in common). Eclipse itself already has some way of walking the AST (for example the Outline view). Is there an easier way to get this data?

Comment: Read about the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to do what `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.AbstractJavaEditorTextHover#getJavaElementsAt(ITextViewer, IRegion)` does, specifically to get to the point where you can call `org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICodeAssist#codeSelect(int, int)` and determine to which elements the selected text refers (from 0 to *n*, the interface type in the returned array also indicating what kind of language element it is).

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I'm having some issues in figuring out how to get the correct Region. I'm using `JavaWordFinder.findWord(IDocument, int)` to figure out the IRegion that the `getJavaElementsAt` method needs. I have the IDocument parameter covered, but the second parameter is an offset that I can't figure out how to get.

Comment: How is your functionality triggered? Where does it plug in?

Comment: I figured it out! The offset is provided by the ITextViewer's ITextSelection. I copied getCodeAssist from getJavaElementsAt to my class with an IEditorPart as a parameter. Here's [a sample of my code](https://gist.github.com/theokyr/32f08a1f03a0614aa0ee87940b8756fb) for anyone with a similar question. Thanks for the help!